# Powershell+Sharepoint Online: Recycle Bin Recovery to Target Path

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, recycle-bin, disaster-recovery

Using Powershell, I have found it possible to audit and restore the recycle bin using: `Get-PnPRecycleBinItem` and `Restore-PnpRecycleBinItem`. What I cannot find though is how I would go about sending the recovered file to a designated location *rather* than the original. This particular mass-delete is requiring global action and I'd like to restore everything very carefully into a new sharepoint site and then sort it out from there with the user.

Is it possible to retrieve items from the recycle bin and restore to a target location? I'm willing to script this out - I thought about simply copying it from here and then deleting it to stage2 recycle bin to keep myself organized - that's not bad but I'm not sure how I would engage in a copy from this location.

My only other thought was to restore it, building a list all the while, and then to go through and move it to another location and delete the folder if/when required. Much more complex and way more noise for the sync client of all the users during this ~300k item process...

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we cannot move items in the recycle bin to other locations directly.  You have to restore the items in the recycle bin to original location, then move these files/folders to  another location.